# New Ideas for a observable Quantum Spin experment

Tags: quantum-spin

After hearing about the new state of matter-Quantum Spin Liquid, I got interested in how these experiments would take place and what is expected to be observed. After searching for some videos online I only found CGI experiment of carbon atoms being shot between opposite polar magnets and observing how some atoms would have a upward arc placement and some having a downward arc placement.

**Are there any new ideas for a observable experiment showing the Mechanics behind the Quantum Spin of a electron?**

Answer (score 1):

The spin quantization was first detected by the Stern-Gerlach experiment. This one ingenious experiment proved that the spin is an observable. Refer to the experiment. I prefer the book:
Modern Quantum Mechanics by J.J.Sakurai.  chapter 1

Comment: This is the same experiment I mentioned in my question. Im asking for a new way of observing quantum spin via 3d real life observable experiment. You don't know how to perform a different experiment to observe Quantum Spin?

Comment: An observable experiment at the quantum level is something vague, your observation change its state.